# Error While launching activity in android studio after the app installation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-emulator, build.gradle

I have created an app in android studio 3.5 version where there is only an image view in constraint layout. But when I am running the app in emulator then the following error is displayed :

> Displayed Error:

```
    11/08 11:27:31: Launching 'app' on 3.7  WVGA (Nexus One) API 22.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.trialanderror/com.example.trialanderror.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.trialanderror/com.example.trialanderror.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.trialanderror/.MainActivity }

Error while Launching
```

> The XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/beer" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> The Main Activity:

```
package com.example.trialanderror;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

  }
```

> Android Screen Shot:

[image]

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml file:
(When i opened it the displayed message is : 
App is not indexable by google search; consider adding at least one activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter
Issue id: GoogleAppIndexWarning )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.trialanderror">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you add your manifest file ?

Comment: run adb logcat to see the detailed error. make sure the activity is declared in the manifest

Comment: Added the AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

First, define the Imageview in the Main activity onCreate.

```
ImageViewer imageView = (ImageViewer)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

And then make sure the image which you are using in the ImageViewer is in .png format. If the problem is still there check your AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have placed this page in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: please tell me how to place that.

Comment: I have included the AndroidManifest.xml file in the question